# Creating a document with mixed languages

Tags: babel, languages

I am typing a document in both Chinese and Hebrew. When I use the following codes for Chinese, everything works fine:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \begin{abstract}
        这是简介及摘要。
    \end{abstract}

    \section{ 前言 }

    \section{关于数学部分}
    数学、中英文皆可以混排。You can intersperse math, Chinese and English (Latin script) without adding extra environments.

    這是繁體中文。

\end{document}
```

But when I tried to add Hebrew by adding

`\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}`

It does not compile properly. The error message was

> Font LHE/cmr/m/n/10=jerus10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \select@language{hebrew}

Anyone knows how to fix the problem?

Comment: The problem is that, by default, babel is trying to load a legacy 8-bit font you don’t have installed. The fix is to switch to Unicode and use `\babelprovide[import=he]{hebrew}`, then `\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}` (or another font).

Comment: I'll post a working example later.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Updated Answer

As of July 2020, it is possible to have `babel` select the correct language and font based on the language of the characters in the source.  This allows me to post a complete answer to your question, which genuinely requires no explicit language tagging in the body of the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{iftex}

\ifluatex
  \usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase,
                        Ligatures=TeX,
                        Renderer=HarfBuzz }
\else
  \usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase,
                        Ligatures=TeX }
\fi

\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{chinese-simplified}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{chinese-traditional}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0, Ligatures=Common]{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures=Common]{Latin Modern Sans}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}
          [Language=Default,
           UprightFont=*-Medium,
           ItalicFont=*-MediumItalic,
           BoldFont=*-Bold,
           BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
           Extension=.otf
          ]{DavidCLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}
          [Language=Default]{Miriam CLM}
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{rm}
          {Noto Serif CJK SC}
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{sf}
          {Noto Sans CJK SC}
\babelfont[chinese-traditional]{rm}
          {Noto Serif CJK TC}
\babelfont[chinese-traditional]{sf}
          {Noto Sans CJK TC}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \begin{abstract}
        这是简介及摘要。
    \end{abstract}

    \section{前言}

    \section{关于数学部分}
    数学、中英文皆可以混排。 You can intersperse
    math, Chinese and English (Latin script) או עברית
    without adding extra environments.

    這是繁體中文

\end{document}
```

[image: Babel font sample]

This example did not really work correctly.  I find when I look that the traditional Chinese font overrode simplified Chinese.  Only the traditional Chinese font was used in the output, although I believe the simplified Chinese characters used different Unicode codepoints from their traditional counterparts.  Be careful when two languages share the same script!

#### Original Answer

The `[hebrew]` package option of `babel` does not really work any more.  It tries to load a set of legacy fonts in the 8-bit LHE encoding.  (In this case, it is not even looking for a Type 1 font, but the Metafont source for a bitmap font.)  In theory, there’s a package called ivritex floating out there that’s supposed to provide backwards compatibility for this; in practice, the maintainer says that it’s a lot simpler to switch to Unicode.  Using the new toolchain also obviates all the hacks needed to make UTF-8 and Unicode fonts mostly work with an inherently 8-bit TeX engine.

The workaround is to load Hebrew with `\babelprovide[import=he]{hebrew}` instead.  You must then pass the `[bidi=default]` package option to `babel` for bidirectional text to work.  To change the output encoding to Unicode, you need to define a set of fonts with `\babelfont`.

Here’s an example.  I changed the `ctexart` document class to `article` with `babel`, and set all the fonts with `babelfont`, mainly because `ctex` has no English documentation.  I couldn’t tell you how compatible it is with either `babel` or `polyglossia`.  If it’s important to write in multiple languages without special markup, you could try `ucharclasses`, but you might run into problems with right-to-left languages such as Hebrew or Arabic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelprovide[main, import=en, language=Default]{english}
\babelprovide[import=he]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{chinese-simplified}
\babelprovide[import]{chinese-traditional}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0, Ligatures={Common, TeX}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures={Common, TeX}]{Latin Modern Sans}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}
          [Scale=MatchLowercase, Language=Default]{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}
          [Scale=MatchLowercase, Language=Default]{Miriam CLM}
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{rm}
          [Scale=MatchLowercase]{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{sf}
          [Scale=MatchLowercase]{Noto Sans CJK SC}
\babelfont[chinese-traditional]{rm}
          [Scale=MatchLowercase]{Noto Serif CJK TC}
\babelfont[chinese-traditional]{sf}
          [Scale=MatchLowercase]{Noto Sans CJK TC}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \begin{abstract}
      \begin{otherlanguage}{chinese-simplified}
        这是简介及摘要。
      \end{otherlanguage}
    \end{abstract}

    \section{\foreignlanguage{chinese-simplified}{前言}}

    \section{\foreignlanguage{chinese-simplified}{关于数学部分}}
    \foreignlanguage{chinese-simplified}{数学、中英文皆可以混排。} You can intersperse
    math, Chinese and English (Latin script) \foreignlanguage{hebrew}{או עברית}
    without adding extra environments.

    \foreignlanguage{chinese-traditional}{這是繁體中文。}

\end{document}
```

[image: Multilingual sample text]

“Without adding extra environments” is now a blatant lie.  You can make Chinese the `main` language instead of English, but then you will have to localize certain strings such as the Table of Contents.  The call to `geometry` is solely to make the output fit within the allowed image size here.

If you’re writing documents in Chinese and Hebrew, you presumably have fonts for these languages installed on your system already, and can replace the ones I picked with them.  You do not need any special TeX fonts with `fontspec`; any modern system font will work.  If you want to install the fonts I used in this example, you should do so from one of the following sources, in order. A: an operating-system package, such as `fonts-noto-cjk` and `culmus` on Ubuntu; B: a CTAN package, such as `notoCJKsc`; C: from the [Culmus project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/culmus/files/culmus/0.133/) and [the Noto CJK homepage](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/).

This compiles with XeLaTeX, requires Babel 3.27 or later, and is written to work around the bug that `\babelfont` in 3.27 ignores default font features.  There’s already a patch to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My problem is, Package babel Error: You haven't specified a language option. ...ry to proceed from here, type x to quit.} Do you happen to know any fix to this?

Comment: @Zuriel Upgrade to `babel` 3.27.

Comment: @Zuriel If you absolutely can’t, you could try, as a workaround, `\usepackage[bidi, english]{babel}` and commenting out the line  `%\babelprovides[main, import=en]{english}`. But you want to run an recent TeX engine, or you’ll get a lot of problems we can’t help you with.

Comment: @Davislor Hi. This is an off-topic: sorry very much. Please, can you see my recent question for to have a precious your answer? Thank you very much. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512663/a-big-tau-used-in-an-italian-university-book

Comment: Huh, someone un-upvoted it after I posted a more up-to-date answer, without removing the old one they upvoted? If you’re still around, I’m curious why you thought the edit made it that much worse.

Comment: +1: Important update!

Comment: "based on the language of the characters in the source": Are there cases where a character can be part of both languages, like numbers?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, definitely. In those cases, it’s not supposed to change the language, but I haven’t stress-tested that.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner In this case, a bit of testing shows that the Traditional Chinese font overrides the Simplified Chinese font entirely. However, to the best of my limited knowledge, the simplified and traditional characters use different Unicode codepoints anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your research

Comment: Is this supposed to work outside LuaTeX? I'm trying with XeTeX and it seems that Babel *assumes* LuaTeX when `onchar` is provided...

Comment: @gaelicWizard Afraid not. The first MWE only works in LuaLaTeX. It is possible to do the same for certain languages in XeLaTeX, using `ucharclasses`. PDFTeX language support is more ad hoc. I have a few examples up in all three engines for a handful of languages.

Comment: @gaelicWizard The second MWE should work in XeLaTeX. However, it looks like it could use an update, since the workaround for a bug in an old version of `babel` is no longer needed. And I should probably make the `\ifluatex` block actually work.

Comment: @davislor the code in `babel.sty` that handles `onchar` begins immediately with LuaTeX-specific macros, and then the next line is `\directlua`. I can’t imagine how it would work in XeTeX, but I would be very happy to be proven wrong!

Comment: @gaelicWizard I meant the final MWE, the one without `onchar=` or any LuaTeX-specific commands.