# A "big tau" used in an Italian university book

Tags: fonts, pdftex, symbols, packages, fontfamily

Into an Italian university book which translates an English version of Modern Quantum Mechanics J.J. Sakurai, I have finded a strange symbol that never I have seen here into this Community and other books for the use of the LaTeX.

It seem a big tau, for my humble opinion. In fact the theme is an infinitesimal translation or spatial displacement.

[image]

Is it possible to reproduce a similar symbol without a conflict with the packages that I'm using?

For example using a typical structure of this kind:

```
\DeclareFontFamily
\DeclareFontSubstitution
\DeclareFontShape
\renewcommand{\Tau}
```

Your ideas are very welcome.

Comment: Looks like `\mathcal{T}`...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Hi, Phelype. No, no is not the classic calligraphic command, otherwise I would not have asked a question :-)

Comment: The original version does use a calligraphic T as suggested by @PhelypeOleinik.

Comment: @Sebastiano With a different font, of course :-)

Comment: @RalfStubner Hi, I'm asking the italian version :-)..where I can take this font? Best regards.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik And what is the font? :-) I'am searching from an hour :-(.

Comment: Won't be the same font, but with the `scalerel` package you could do `\newcommand\Tau{\scalerel*{\tau}{T}}`.  That will work across math styles, too.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Hi, Steven I have read the book and it has been mainly created with CM. I was very curious if exist the same font. In fact in the tags I have also included: fonts.

Comment: To decide whether this is a calligraphic T or a Tau we should look at other calligraphic and uppercase Greek letters. In the English edition in the beginning of Chapter 2, the time evolution operator is introduced using `\mathcal{U}` What does that look like in your edition? Uppercase Greeks are harder to find. I found a Xi in the last exercise for Chapter 1 and a Gamma in Supplement II "Non-exponential Decays". If these exist in your edition, what do they look like?

Comment: A `τ` on its horizontal  part doesn't have an inflection.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi, I have put the link of the book that's been scanned. If it had not been scanned I would have examined the details of the pdf and see which possible font has been used. I really like the symbol.

Comment: @Bernard I like it a lot this symbol.

Comment: Yes I just looked and realised that. Is that a legal copy? (I looks unlikely)

Comment: as with all your other questions about the shapes of individual letters I'd say it is the wrong question to ask. You pick a font and typeset your version with a coherent set of letters as designed by the font designer. It is far more important that your document is self-consistent than that an individual letter is extracted from an incompatible font set to look like some other publication

Comment: Thanks for the link. To me this makes it clear that it is a calligraphic T. The time evolution operator on book page 69 has the same style as the symbol in question. But there is no uppercase Greek letter that looks like an U. The Xi on book page 66 is in completely style different, though. There is no supplement II and therefore no Gamma to compare. I have no idea which calligraphic math font this is ...

Comment: well if I understand the Italian on the copyright page it says electronic reproduction is not allowed.

Comment: If you have a PDF, you can run `pdffonts` and see which fonts it used.

Comment: @Davislor Hi, if you see one comment to Ralfa Stubner my pdf is the scanned copy of the book. Therefore I have not seen the fonts it used.

Comment: The book's colophon states that TeX was used. How about asking the publisher which fonts they used?

Comment: @RalfStubner Most kind Ralf In fact, I thought about writing to the publishing house to find out which font they used for that symbol that I like. Thank you very much for your patience and your kindness about me.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Most kind Steven, please, can you add an answer following your comment? Thank you very much. I have tried and it works well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the OP's request, I am turning my comment into an answer.

I had suggested using the `\scalerel*` macro to scale the existing lowercase `\tau` to the size of a capital letter.  This approach will work across math styles, as shown in the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
%\usepackage{txfonts}
\newcommand\Tau{\scalerel*{\tau}{T}}
\begin{document} 
$\Tau (dx') = \ldots$\par
$\scriptstyle\Tau (dx') = \ldots$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My most sincere and cordial appreciation...as always.