# Package polyglossia Error: The current latin font does not contain the "Hebrew" script! (LYX NOT TEX)

Tags: fonts, lyx, polyglossia, hebrew

I'm trying to compile a very simple file where i just typed a word (in hebrew, english works fine) into a new document and tried to do "Export [PDF(XeTeX)]", but it just doesn't work. I get the error in the title. I've looked at the other threads with this same question but they seem to all use TeX, but I use LyX.

I've installed LyX and Culmus and all the things that should be needed but it just doesn't work.
Help is very appretiated! thanks.

EDIT: Solved due to a full reinstall of everything related to tex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! In Lyx you can export the compiled tex code (i am not a Lyx user I do not know how;-), please show us this short compilable tex code in your question ...

Comment: @Mensch my bad, that one is with weird preamble configuration that i tried (and it didnt help). this is it without any preambles: https://pastebin.com/SV8t1iNg

Comment: With `polyglossia`, you have to define a `\hebrewfont` command, so `polyglossia` knows which font to use. Tex code e.g., `\newfontface\hebrewfont{David}`. (I don't have `David CLM`). I don't know Lyx.

Comment: @Cicada So i've tried this https://pastebin.com/i5L6SzLp and now the problem is only "Missing glyphs! Missing character: there is no "<hebrew letter>" in font frank!" (<hebrew letter> is just any hebrew letter that it sees in the text (so if i write 4 letters, this error shows up 4 times).

Comment: If you want the document to automatically detect Hebrew and switch fonts, [this template might work for you.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483605/creating-a-document-with-mixed-languages/483612#483612)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved by an update as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Marijn sure, how do i close this? or is it up to the admins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just COMPLETELY reinstalled everything related to TeX so unfortunately I lost my settings and some packages i liked but at least i can compile things normally now. thanks for all the helpers!

EDIT: I don't know why this was deleted. this IS the solution that solved my problem.